# Issue with login function in php

Tags: php, mysql, web

i have problem in my code. First of all works fine with mysqli connection, but then i try do just mysql (becouse my another function only working with mysql not mysqli).Something in my login fucktion dont working, nick and pass are right. In database table name user. Please help me my code

```
require_once('connection.php');
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Login']))
    {
       if(empty($_POST['UName']) || empty($_POST['Password']))
       {
            header("location:index.php?Empty= Please Fill in the Blanks");
       }
       else
       {

            $name = trim($_POST['UName']);
            $pass = trim($_POST['Password']);
            $query="select * from user where nick='".$name."' and pass='".$pass."'";
            $result= mysql_query($con,$query);
              $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($result2['nick'])
            {
                $_SESSION['User']=$name;

                header("location:wellcome.php");
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:index.php?Invalid= Please Enter Correct User Name and Password ".$name." ".$pass." ");
            }
       }
    }
```

So i always get Please enter correct user name.
connection.php

```
   $con=@mysql_connect('localhost','sesseses','DjWJfD4q');
    mysql_select_db('sesseses');
   if(!$con)
   {
       die(' Please Check Your Connection'.mysqli_error($con));
   }
```

Any idea? i cant found solution on my own..

Comment: 1. do not use "$con=@mysql_connect" @ to ignore errers 2. use mysqli* functions or PDO instead of mysql*

Comment: with mysqli doest work this code ```                                                                      
               $user = "select * from user where nick='". $_SESSION['User']."'";
        $q = mysql_query($user);
               $q = mysql_query($user) or die(mysql_error());
              $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);```  Writing no database connection

Comment: and without it doesn't work to! post the error notice!

Comment: With Malik Shukurlu solution login working fine now .

Comment: On another subject, be careful, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Somebody can run SQL queries by writing SQL command into the Username and Password field.  You should consider prepared statements. There's plenty of documentation online on how to do that.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!x** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
$result= mysql_query($con,$query);
```

Correct version:

```
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You must know:
PHP mysql_ functions are officially **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013) and has been **removed entirely** as of PHP 7.0 (released December 2015).
Please use mysqli_ instead of mysql_.

Comment: i wish use what, but then my another code dont work, and write no database connection `$user = "select * from user where nick='". $_SESSION['User']."'"; $q = mysql_query($user); $q = mysql_query($user) or die(mysql_error()); $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);`

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem here. Try these: **1)** In your config file write these codes and fill $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname: `$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); if (!mysqli_select_db($db,$dbname)) { echo 'MySQLi database not selected: ' . mysqli_connect_errno(); exit; }`. 
**2)** In your php file: `$user = "select * from user where nick='". $_SESSION['User']."'";  $q = mysqli_query($con, $user) or die(mysqli_error($con)); $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);`

Comment: Yeah, you need the `i` version (`mysqli`) or your code will be instantly irrelevant.